# Redirecting automatically upon session expiry

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to redirect a page upon session expiry(automatically) with out any user action on the page.?

Comment: Is it a page specific time out, or just a general session timeout? I.E. from the moment someone lands on a page, start the timer, or when the session is created, start the timer? You could use ajax to ping the server to check. Or set a meta refresh time on a page per page basis?

Comment: If i call use timer and Ajax function to server every time i call ajax the session will get recreated rite..? how do i access session variable with out recreating the session ..?

Comment: If you create a session variable upon first initiating the session you can then check this variable timer at any point by calling session_start(); and then checking $_SESSION['timer']; The timer won't be reset until you actively reset it

Comment: I think u didn't get my question. I have page where in i need to keep seeing whether session got expired or not.The code should be client side (java script) it can not be of server side code as it will never allow session to get expire.

Answer (score 6):

Create an activity checker which checks every minute if any user activity has taken place (mouseclick, keypress) and performs a heartbeat to the server side to keep the session alive when the user is active and does nothing when the user is not active. When there is no activity for 30 minutes (or whatever default session timeout is been set on server side), then perform a redirect.

Here's a kickoff example with little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to bind click and keypress events and fire ajax request.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.active = false;
        $('body').bind('click keypress', function() { $.active = true; });
        checkActivity(1800000, 60000, 0); // timeout = 30 minutes, interval = 1 minute.
    });

    function checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed) {
        if ($.active) {
            elapsed = 0;
            $.active = false;
            $.get('heartbeat');
        }
        if (elapsed < timeout) {
            elapsed += interval;
            setTimeout(function() {
                checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed);
            }, interval);
        } else {
            window.location = 'http://example.com/expired'; // Redirect to "session expired" page.
        }
    }
</script>
```

Create a `Servlet` which listens on `/heartbeat` and does basically just the following:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    request.getSession();
}
```

to keep the session alive.

Comment: Indeed one of your best answers ever, this should be at +1000