# Ajax calls don't renew session timeout on Tomcat 6

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I migrated my webapp from Tomcat 5.5 to Tomcat 6(.0.32). In that app there are ajax calls in every footer page to avoid session timeout. It works fine on Tomcat 5.5 but it doesn't work in Tomcat 6. I use a filter to track every call in a DB table. On non-ajax calls I can see the tracking in the table and the reset session timeout. On ajax calls I can see the tracking in the table but not the reset of the session timeout.

Why? Can I change this behavior? And, just for info, how can Tomcat6 distinguish the ajax calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not explicitly accessing the session in response to the AJAX calls, you may need to set the [`org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Specification) system property. Of course, that may also impact other parts of your app. Another option would be to ensure that you do explicitly access the session...

Comment: Indeed, just doing `request.getSession()` ought to be enough. See also [this related topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417503/redircting-automatically-upon-session-expiry).

Comment: Thanks both. I read about STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIACNE and I fear about its impact. So I'll use request.getSession() in that calls (just a few little changes).