# Session Destroyed; Print Message in JSP and Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When a session has been destroyed, how do I print a message on a JSP that notifies the user? I'm using a class that implements HttpSessionListener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the session is destroyed, you can't do anything from the server side on anyway. At the point of session destroy there is no guarantee that you have valid request/response objects at your hands. Your best bet is to handle it fully at the client side, using for example JS. You can get the remaining lifetime of the current session by [`HttpSession#getMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29) and you can use JavaScript's [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) to run a function after some time.

```xml
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Session has timed out!';
    }, ${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval} * 1000); // It returns seconds, but setTimeout expects milliseconds.
</script>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: Did you read the paragraph above the code snippet? Do you know better client side languages? Feel free to post an answer if you have a better approach.

Comment: @Op, it's impossible to print a message for the client when an event like this occurs on the server-side, because there is no client when the event occurs

Comment: @BalusC If you are referring to: _When the session is destroyed, you can't do anything from the server side on anyway._ ***That is plain wrong.*** The client still sends the session cookie. So, you can check on the server, if the cookie is present and there is no session, then it time-outed. The question is answered somewhere around.

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: This requires a request after the timeout. I understood that the OP needs to display the message immediately. So there's no means of a request.

Comment: If you really wanted to you could initiate an AJAX call that checks the server side if the session still exists but this solution is sufficient for most cases.

Comment: As per the comment of @Abdullah, you may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417503/redircting-automatically-upon-session-expiry/5420266#5420266

Comment: Thank you all for the input and debate :)